# Using CocoaPods with Notification Content extensions

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

Is it possible to use Cocoa Pods with Notification Content extensions? If so, what do I need to do?

I have used pods with keyboard extension where all I needed to do was to include:

```
target 'host-app' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Kingfisher', :git => 'https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git', :branch => 'swift4'

  target 'keyboard-extension' do
     inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

And I was able to use the Kingfisher there. However, when I try the same with notification content extension (rich notifications), the Xcode is still not able to recognize the `Kingfisher` in `import Kingfisher`.

Comment: even after building? Xcode needs to build before its editor will recognize modules from CocoaPods.

Comment: `pod install`, then clean the project, and attempt to build.. and the attempt failed, because the xcode did not "see" the library

Comment: I've always just explicitly listed the pod again in the extension without issues.

Comment: @Gargoyle but was it in notification content extension or some other? Because with keyboard extension it worked like a charm, with notifications I wasn’t able to make it work. Is it possieble that one app extension type is not supported and another type is?

Comment: Yes it was in the extension